# react-native dynamic create dialog and show

Tags: react-native

In my app, I want to use a Modal/Dialog for login, some pages can use this when some action needs user info but user is not login.

That means I needs to do the same things to those pages.

1. Add login Modal/Dialog to the page component
2. Add check user info method to the page
3. Add callback to the login Modal/Dialog, for listen user login or cancel action

Is there a way to create a Modal like this:

```
class SomeView extends Components {
    render() {
        return (<Button onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} title="toLogin"/>)
    }

    onPress() {
         // dynamic create a Modal/Dialog and show
         var dialog = new LoginDialog(...);
         dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This package is pretty good: https://github.com/victoriafrench/react-native-dialogbox

Comment: Many thanks, I will try to using this, but this not a pretty solution,  It's still need to add <DialogBox .../> to all pages

Comment: That's true, I also wish there was a simpler way to make modal dialogs but it doesn't look like there's any package like this at the moment. What I've ended up doing for my application is a wrapper around the above package, which makes things a bit easier but still tedious.